# what does this variable name do in the Do-While loop expression and what is the meaning of its existence in it?

Tags: c++, integer, reverse, do-while, long-integer

im trying to learn how to reverse a number but came across a problem about this Do-While loop. Specifically
`while (n1)`. Usually i just see people put in a condition with about comparison.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{

    long int n1, n2, Rinteger = 0;
    cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
    cin >> n1;
    n2 = n1;
    do
    {
        Rinteger *= 10; 
        int digit = n1 % 10; 
        Rinteger += digit;
        n1 /= 10; 
    } while (n1);
    
    cout << "Initial integer: " << n2 << "." << endl;
    cout << "Reversed integer: " << Rinteger << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways to reverse an integer but i am curious about how does this Do-While loop works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(n1)` without a comparison just means `while (n1 != 0)` (C treats zero/`NULL` values as false, all other values as true). So the loop body is always entered once (thanks to being a `do`/`while`, rather than a plain `while`), and continues as long as `n1` is not reduced to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. It really all make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This means to repeat while `n1` is `true`. In C++, an `int` is considered `true` when it's nonzero.

Comment: oh yes it does really make sense now. Thank you Lorro.

Answer (score 0):

**while** loop only enter´s if the condition is true.
**do-while** loop enter´s at least once, then check if the condition is true to continues.